# How to add limit to iview ui multiple select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, iview

I am trying to add limit to iView ui `Multiple select`. Here is the code

```
<Select
     v-model="data.category"
     :multiple="true"
     filterable
     remote
     :remote-method="remoteMethod2"
     :loading="loading2">
     <Option v-for="(option, index) in options2" :value="option.value" :key="index">{{option.label}}</Option>
</Select>
```

I want to add something like this `max="3"` to limit the selected items

Couldn't find anything in api doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property with that functionality, but we could do it ourselves by watching the length of our `model` that contains the selected items and if it's equal to the fixed `max` in data object properties we change the `disabled` property state to `true` and if remove an item from the selected ones we could also enable the options drop down, check th following example that explains itself :

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
    disable:false,
      max: 2,
      cityList: [{
          value: 'New York',
          label: 'New York'
        },
        {
          value: 'London',
          label: 'London'
        },
        {
          value: 'Sydney',
          label: 'Sydney'
        },
        {
          value: 'Ottawa',
          label: 'Ottawa'
        },
        {
          value: 'Paris',
          label: 'Paris'
        },
        {
          value: 'Canberra',
          label: 'Canberra'
        }
      ],
      model10: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    model10(val) {
      if (val.length == this.max) this.disable=true
      else this.disable=false
    },
   
  }
}

var Component = Vue.extend(Main)
new Component().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app {
  padding: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <i-select v-model="model10" multiple style="width:260px">
    <i-option :disabled="disable" v-for="item in cityList" :value="item.value" :key="item.value">{{ item.label }}</i-option>
  </i-select>
</div>
```